# how to open a highcharts graph in a popup window?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, popup

I need to open a popup window and display a highcharts graph by clicking on a button in my main window.
I found many discussions and samples about how to open a larger graph in a popup from an existing graph in the current page, but this doesnt fit my needs.
Can anyone outline the way to do so ?

regards,
oliver

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: of course SO is not there to write for me ! I wrote "outline". I have used a <div> in my page as a container, filled from jquery with a highcharts object. I know how to fire a popup form javascript, but I have no idea how to "inject" my chart code in it. I spent quite some time browsing existing answers before asking, but found no hints corresponding to my case.

Comment: The same way you open anything else in a popup window.  For more specific help, provide a more specific question, with examples of your code, and what specific problem(s) you are having with it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example showing how you can open your chart in new tab:

You can use window.open() method to open a new page in the tab after you will click on your button:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

In your window you can add your container and your script using appendChild() and html() methods:
http://api.jquery.com/html/
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

```
function(chart) {
    $('#newTab').click(function() {
      var options = chart.userOptions,
        container = chart.renderTo,
        w,
        html = '<div id="' + container.id + '" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
        s1 = document.createElement('script'),
        s2 = document.createElement('script'),
        s3 = document.createElement('script'),
        s4 = document.createElement('script');
      t = document.createTextNode('$(function() {$("#' + container.id + '").highcharts(' + JSON.stringify(options) + ')})');
      s3.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      s3.appendChild(t);
      s4.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
      s1.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js');
      s2.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js');
      w = window.open("", '_blank', "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
      w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s4);
      setTimeout(function() {
        w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s1);
        setTimeout(function() {
          w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s2);
          $(w.document.body).html(html);
          w.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s3);
        }, 100)
      }, 100)

    });
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gtyLtd71/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot Grzegorgz ! your sample is very clear on how to inject the scripts in the new window. I will work in this direction on my app and make a feedback later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can show chart in modal window by double clicking on chart like http://jsfiddle.net/asadsarwar89/27k5bj5k/
with some css and JS:

```
$('.chart-container').bind('dblclick', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('modal');
    $('.chart', this).highcharts().reflow();
});
```

also this event can be bound to button click event.

Comment: Thanks Asad for the interesting info, but again this suppose that a chart is already plotted in the page. I was looking to plot the chart in the new popup window only.